# Ignore Jackson property

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
{admin": false,
    "email": "student@student.com",
    "firstName": "Student",
    "idGroup": {
      "idGroup": 1,
      "name": "BlijkbaarGeenGroep",
      "teacher": {
        "admin": true,
        "email": "1",
        "firstName": "Example",
        "idUser": 1,
        "lastName": "User",
        "teacher": true
      }
    }
```

The folliwing is returned. What I want jackson todo is to ignore teacher. I don't really care about the teacher items for this call. Problem is I don't want to access the GroupEntity because I do need groupinfo sometimes.

```
     package org.hva.folivora.daomodel.user;

    import com.owlike.genson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
    import com.owlike.genson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
    import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreType;
    import org.hva.folivora.daomodel.global.GroupEntity;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;

    /**
     * @author
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Student", schema = "pad_ijburg", catalog = "")
    public class StudentEntity extends UserEntity implements Serializable {
        private GroupEntity idGroup;

        public StudentEntity(String email, String firstName, String lastName, String password, GroupEntity idGroup) {
            //A student cannot be an admin or teacher. (False, False)
            super(email, firstName, lastName, password, false, false);
            this.idGroup = idGroup;
        }

        public StudentEntity() {

        }

//Something like ignore all but idgroup??!
        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "idGroup")
        public GroupEntity getIdGroup() {
            return idGroup;
        }

        public void setIdGroup(GroupEntity idGroup) {
            this.idGroup = idGroup;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple options:

1. Put `@JsonIgnoreProperties` on your `StudentEntity` class. See: [JsonIgnoreProperties (Jackson-annotations 2.7.4 API)](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.7.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html).
2. Write a custom `JsonSerializer` for `StudentEntity`. Here you will have to write down code that constructs each field for the output JSON. See: [Jackson - Custom Serializer | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization).
3. Use a Mixin, which is basically an interface that matches your `StudentEntity`. Here you can use `@JsonIgnore` on the `getTeacher()` method. See: [JacksonMixInAnnotations · FasterXML/jackson-docs Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations).
4. Put a `@JsonSerialize` on you `idGroup` property within your `StudentEntity` class. The annotation takes a class as argument that implements `JsonSerializer`. Though you can specify a way to serialize the `idGroup` property if (and only if) Jackson serializes an instance of `StudentEntity`. (this is more or less just like *option `2.`*, but much more simple to implement)
5. Write a DTO class that matches your output format. Then copy field by field from your `StudentEntity` object to the `StudentEntityDTO` object (which doesn't have a `teacher` property) and then let Jackson serialize the DTO object instead of the original `StudentEntity` object. That's a lot of code to write and only useful if the output JSON is really much different from the original object.

I'd go for one of the first four options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @JsonIgnoreProperties seems the way to go. Could you update your example with my data. I'm still trying to implement it.

Comment: I've never used it with nested properties. I'd expect that either `@JsonIgnoreProperties("idGroup.teacher")` on `class StudentEntity` works. Or `@JsonIgnoreProperties("teacher")` on your `getIdGroup()` method. Or maybe on the `private GroupEntity idGroup` field.

Comment: Mm, I'm getting confused with versions at the moment. I'm using JAX-RS For building an API. I previously used com.owlike.genson, but for some reason that doesn't include @JsonIgnoreProperties. I'm getting that from codehaus, which won't work in combination. Any idea?

Comment: Allright. I fixed it myself, kinda got confused with the maven versions. But that's done now. Great thanks for your help it's fixed!!

Answer (score 0):

Put @JsonIgnore on getter of teacher, it will not come in out put json

Comment: This way he would have to modify the `GroupEntity` class. In his question it seemed to me, that he does only want to ignore the `teacher` property when an instance of `StudentEntity` is getting serialized.

Comment: @BenjaminM Correct!